# Passing a variable value between activities

Tags: java, android, variables, android-activity, send

I am trying to pass a number from an EditText box in activity1 to activity2 when a button is pressed, I then want the number to appear in a toast or dialog box when an action bar button is pressed in activity2. I have set up an intent and coded what I think should work but it seems to be crashing activity2 everytime. I put in the line of code that should fetch the variable. Hopefully someone will be able to see where it is I'm going wrong. I know passing the data within a variable should be a fairly easy task. 
 Any help would be appreciated.

```
Activity1:

public class activity1 extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.screen_settings);
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

final EditText inputTxt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.conPhoneNum);    
Button saveBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave1);


  saveBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
          String phoneNum1 = inputTxt1.getText().toString();
          savenum1(phoneNum1);

  Intent passIntent = new Intent();
  passIntent.putExtra("phoneNum", phoneNum1);

    }
    });
}


public void savenum1(String phoneNum1) {

AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

dlgAlert.setMessage("Saved " + phoneNum1);
dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);

dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          //dismiss the dialog  
        }
    });    
dlgAlert.create().show();
}
}
```

Activity2:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

      //This is the line that stops the activity from running
String conPhoneNum = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phoneNum");


@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
actionBar.show();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
 }


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu1(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}





@Override  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_load:
     Toast toast= Toast.makeText(this, conPhoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, -100);
          toast.show();
      break;

         default:
             break;
             }
    return true;
    } 
 }
```

LogCat information:

```
07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.cam.data /com.cam.data.Activity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity     (ActivityThread.java:2135)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700    (ActivityThread.java:140)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage     (ActivityThread.java:1237)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage     (Handler.java:99)
07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main    (ActivityThread.java:4921)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.cam.data.Activity2.onCreate(Activity2.java:66)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at      android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
```

**UPDATE 1:**
`conPhoneNum = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phoneNum");` is still crashing the activity. I have found that if i remove `.getExtras()` then it will not crash but it also will not display the data. I don't know if this is any kind of indicator as to why its making the app crash? maybe someone can help

**UPDATE 2:**
just an update on this, I ended up scrapping this and just using global variables defined in a global class that can be used by any activity at any time. It seems to be a much better way of doing this kind of thing unless of course you absolutely need to pass the variable.
Obviously it would be good if someone could work out why it wouldn't work, incase other people come across this problem

Comment: if its a crash pls post the stack trace.

Comment: What is at line 66 of `Activity2`?

Comment: You might also need to post updated code...just the relevant parts and don't overwrite your original code

Comment: conPhoneNum = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phoneNum"); is at line 66. I don't know why but it seems like something about this line of code is causing it to crash

Comment: @AndroidCB is it inside `oncreate` could you post the updated code?

Comment: Assuming you now have that line in `onCreate()`, after your `super` call, post just the part of how you are creating and sending the `Intent`

Comment: conPhoneNum = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phoneNum"); is within onCreate() and after super. do you want me to post the code within activity1 that sends the Intent??

Comment: Code in activity1 to send intent:
 Intent passIntent = new Intent(SettingsScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
              passIntent.putExtra("phoneNum", phoneNum1);
              startActivity(passIntent);

Comment: Does anybody know why this line would crash my activity??

Comment: I don't see any reason for `NPE` there. Put a breakpoint in there and see what is `null`.

Comment: I just can't understand why it would make it crash

Comment: just to let you guys know, I've ended up just setting up a global variables class to handle variables that can be accessed by all my activities. Not really what I wanted to do but it does serve as a solution to my problem

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

```
  Intent passIntent = new Intent();
  passIntent.putExtra("phoneNum", phoneNum1);
```

By

```
  Intent passIntent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
  passIntent.putExtra("phoneNum", phoneNum1);
  startActivity(passIntent);
```

To get in Activity2 :

Declare `conPhoneNum` as class member

```
  String conPhoneNum ;
```

In `onCreate`

```
  conPhnoneNum = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phoneNum");
```

Then

```
  Toast toast= Toast.makeText(this, conPhoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Comment: Its still crashing :s if I comment out the conPhoneNum = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phoneNum"); line then it doesn't crash. as soon as the line's put back in it crashes

Comment: @AndroidCB did you move that line in `onCreate` ? if you don't post the logcat it doesn't help solving the problem

Comment: yeah hold on i'll get the logcat

Comment: it seems like no matter where i place it within my code, it crashes the application

Comment: @AndroidCB line 66 of activtiy2 pls.

Comment: conPhoneNum = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phoneNum"); is at line 66. I don't know what it is about this line that is causing it to crash :s

Comment: Does anybody know why this line would crash my activity??

Answer (score 0):

Move this

```
String conPhoneNum = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phoneNum");
```

to `onCreate()` or at least the initialization

```
String conPhoneNum; 


@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

conPhoneNum = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phoneNum");  // here

ActionBar actionBar = getActionBa
```

`getIntent()` will return `null` before the `Activity` is created so you must not call it before.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it does still seem to crash though :s

Comment: @AndroidCB its better if you post the stack trace.

Comment: Then post the logcat. And look at Raghunandan's answer...much more thorough

Answer (score 0):

In your first Activity:

```
Intent passIntent = new Intent();
passIntent.putExtra("phoneNum", phoneNum1);
startActivity(intent)
```

And in the second activity:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
String conPhoneNum = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phoneNum");
```